# Keyboard Input methods changes automatically to a different one which is not in the settings

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I have just one input method, one language settings in Language settings. These are the screen shots of my language and input methods settings.

Settings in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language:

[image]

But in language bar I'm seeing like this:

[image: Settings Shown in Language Bar]

Its automatically changing the input method. How can I disable this?

I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty Simple

1. Go to Taskbar Click on **ENG**

[image]

2. Once you Click in You see Language Prefereneces
3. You can see Region & Language in new windows
4. Click on **Remove** Button the Language which you dont want.

[image]

And also you can see REGISTRY

- `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`

  Name 1 has the default keyboard value per language.

  You can add 2, 3 as well. other Language you can delete if you dont want.

Comment: That is not the problem. In language bar, there is showing 2 different language . But in Region & Language window , there is just one language.

[link](http://imgur.com/a/I2JzK)

Here is the screenshot.
I also checked the registry. In there also just 1 language.

Comment: In Region & Language windows, Click on that English Language and Go to Option. Do you find any keyboard is added there??

Comment: yes.. Just one US (QWERTY).

Comment: Is ur country Bangladesh?..  in registry u have only one entry. Restart your pc and check the registry u have another entry

Comment: Ya, Bangladesh. Did the restart process. No solution yet.

Comment: Something is wrong in os I believe.. better add the same language again.. and restart your pc.. again remove the same language u added.. again restart it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try to get installed keyboards into sync by

1. Adding some other keyboard, e.g. *French*. Make it the default keyboard layout.
2. Add *Bangla* layout and remove your *English US* layout.
3. Log out and back in (or restart the computer). (Warning, if you use password, the keyboard can have differently placed special characters. Or use on-screen keyboard and you cannot be wrong.)
4. After logon, install *English US*, make it default and remove *Bangla* and *French* layout.
5. Log out and back in once more (or restart).

Both *Bangla* and *French* keyboard should be now gone. If you still have *Bangla* keyboard after going through all the steps, let me know. The problem could be then elsewhere.